# Wildcard operator ^ Not working as expected

Tags: sql, sql-server, wildcard

When I use:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM Customers1
WHERE email LIKE '%[^@]%'
```

There are no customers on the output at all, when there should be two on the output. Any ideas what might be causing this? I need to find customers email addresses which don't contain the '@'symbol.

I've tried running code:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM Customers1
WHERE email LIKE '%[@]%';
```

This shows 13 on the output.

I've also tried the '%[!@]%'; but this makes no difference.

Comment: What's wrong with just using `not like '%@%'`?

Comment: `LIKE '%[^@]%'` and `LIKE '%[@]%'` aren't opposites from a boolean logic point of view. The first would return any row which has any character that isn't an `@` in it (so `'a@b'` would be a hit, as `a` and `b` aren't `@`). The latter will match any string that has a `@` character. This means that you have 13 rows where the email address is just `'@'`, and any other rows have the value `''` or `NULL`, *if* what you say is true. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hj64l6ic)

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding, you are trying to get all the email in a table that is not a valid mail address (by checking that email must have @ symbol in it).

The way you are trying to achieve this will not work as this will fetch all data in the column except the null and blank (empty string) data.

[^] wildcard will check LIKE and PATINDEX in some special cases like.

1. A column has only single characters.
2. You are fetching a string where a specific position has not that value, etc.

For this scenario I will rather suggest, use a simple TSQL like.
SELECT *
FROM Customers1
WHERE email NOT LIKE '%@%';